# How do I switch between different contexts in CoolStorage

Tags: coolstorage

I ave different databases with the same schema, the only difference is the connectionstring.
Is it possible to use the context options in CoolStorage to switch the context of the CoolStorage instance to another SQL instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently only supported if you call ad-hoc queries. For example:

```
CSDatabase.Context["ContextName"].ExecuteNonQuery("...");
```

For object-mapped operations, it is not supported. Every mapped class has to be mapped to a specific context at compile-time.